# Create Table with no borders with columns varying depending upon row number?

Tags: tables

I currently have a tag called "`specEntry`" that uses an `env` definition to document the following entries:

i.e.

```
\begin{specEntry}{\-N\-A\-M\-E\-:}
  \-f\-o\-o
\end{specEntry}
\begin{specEntry}{\-T\-Y\-P\-E\-:}
  \-i\-n\-t
\end{specEntry}
\begin{specEntry}{\-V\-A\-L\-U\-E\-:}
  \-7
\end{specEntry}
\begin{specEntry}{\-C\-O\-M\-M\-E\-N\-T\-:}
  \-f\-o\-o \-c\-o\-m\-m\-e\-n\-t
\end{specEntry}
```

Based upon my stylesheet definition, it comes out in the document this way:
   **NAME:** foo
   **TYPE:** int
   **VALUE:** 7
   **COMMENTS:** foo comment

But, I would like it to come out looking like the following (with type and value on the same line - value starting in the center of the page):
   **NAME:** foo
   **TYPE:** int            **VALUE:** 7
   **COMMENTS:** foo comment

specEntry in my stylesheet currently looks like the following:

```
\newenvironment{specEntry}[1]{  
  \begin{list}{}  
  {  
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{40pt}  
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{3cm}  
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}  
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-4pt}  
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{textbf{#1}}  
  }  
  \item[#1]  
}{  
  \end{list}  
}
```

Should I create separate tags that have different style sheet entries (meaning "Name" and "Comments" use one entry and "Type/Value" using another?  Can I create a table that has no borders and basically has 3 rows with only the 2nd row having two columns?  The first arg is always bolded and comments can contain multiple lines. I have tried multiple implementations, but I keep messing the spacing up in the document.  Thanks.

The "COMMENTS" entry could have a long run on paragraph that needs to wrap text in the document, but may have forced newlines as well:

```
\specEntry{COMMENT}{This field represents the color of an object blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \par
0 = RED \par
1 = BLUE \par
2 = YELLOW \par
3 = GREEN}
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Any chance you might share `specEntry` with us since that seems rather key to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an environment form for each entry looks a bit verbose, I'd do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{specEntries}
 {\flushleft}
 {\endflushleft}

\newcommand\specEntry[2]{\makebox[\csname width#1\endcsname][l]{\textbf{#1:} #2}\linebreak[0]\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\widthNAME{\textwidth}
\newcommand\widthTYPE{.5\textwidth}
\newcommand\widthVALUE{.5\textwidth}
\newcommand\widthCOMMENT{\textwidth}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{specEntries}
\specEntry{NAME}{foo}
\specEntry{TYPE}{int}
\specEntry{VALUE}{7}
\specEntry{COMMENT}{foo comment}
\end{specEntries}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I implemented this in my code and it compiles cleanly, but for some reason everything is blank where the entries should be (space seems to be allocated, though).  I have looked at this multiple times and I am very confused as what you provided makes sense.  I will continue to look further as I am sure it is something I am doing, but any ideas?

Comment: @charizard711 not really any idea: you could change `{#1:} #2` to `{(#1:)} [[[#2]]]` and check that the brackets at least appear...

Comment: Totally confused... not even using my code anymore. Just compiling what you have above and getting the "X......X", but nothing else???

Comment: @charizard711 sorry can't help with that, the code above produces the image shown, try copying it again into a new file.

Comment: D'oh!  I knew it was my fault, but missed the obvious... I should have looked at the arguments to makebox first... I was using a "1" instead of an "l" (signifying flushleft).  Unfortunately, I am on a different platform and had to type it in... if I were to copy/paste, it would not have been an issue.  I was definitely going off on tangents looking for the issue.  My fault for always thinking there is an index between brackets.  This will work well now.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I get the "COMMENT" entry to wrap text when it is multiple sentences as well as have newlines when directed in the code (i.e. \par).   I modified my original question with an example.

Comment: @charizard711 change `\makebox[\csname width#1\endcsname][l]{` to `\parbox[t]{\csname width#1\endcsname}{\raggedright`

Comment: Just got back to this format issue and the last suggestion worked great.  Currently, everything works for 99% of the comments (COMMENT tag), but I have a few comments that are longer than a page and are going past the margins and disappearing into oblivion.  Is there a way control when to paginate the comments with the format we have set up now?